# python 3: way to define a function to accept any string input from varying test cases?

Tags: string, python-3.x, functional-programming, testcase

I am trying to run this code in python against test cases and have it accept any string input from the test cases without specifically stating string declaration.
example: string = "string of letters to make a sentence"

the following is my code:

```
def to_weird_case(string):
    index = 0
    new_string = ''
    for word in string:
        if word == ' ':
            index = -1
            new_string += word
        elif index % 2 == 0:
            new_string += word.upper()
        else:
            new_string += word.lower()
        index += 1
    return new_string
print(to_weird_case(string))
```

however when i run the code, i get a 'string' is not defined error (with no line reference). I feel like i defined it but i am new to python and welcome all the destroying im about to get for even asking this but im trying to learn, so if this helps me understand what i did wrong then so be it.

Comment: `print(to_weird_case(string))`: `string` is not defined here...

Comment: This line `print(to_weird_case(string))` you haven't told it what string to use. You've just written `string`. Try `print(to_weird_case("some text here"))`.

Comment: Next time remember `string` is not a good variable name as it's the name of a python module

Comment: so it was against test cases and i realized that the print statement was outside the function, so i hit it with a good ol' fashioned tab and it works! sorry for the lame question, been bashing my head on my desk for this for over an hour to find out it was an indenting error.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variable named `string` without having assigned a value to it.

Before you use the function `to_weird_case`, You first have to say somewhere to what the variable `string` is equal to. For example:

```
string = 'blabla'
```

Then you can use your function on it.

Answer (score 1):

It's just as Tnerual said. In more detail:

Your function is fine, but at the end of your function definition, you called your function with a variable `string`. However, you never assigned a value to `string`.